# How do I run an Internet Explorer application through WebBrowser?

Tags: excel, vba

I've created this code that simulates my actual application. And I'm trying to run the procedure through WebBrowser1. If in my actual application it was possible to use .document.getElementById would work, but you need .getElementsByClassName or TagName. How could I do this with the data below? 
The code application is executed by the CommandButton and the WebBrowser will be inside a Userform.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim IE As InternetExplorer

Dim iELE As Object

Dim xUser As String

Dim xPswd As String



Set IE = New InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate ("https://twitter.com/login?lang=pt")

xUser = "your username"

xPswd = "your password"

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))


        Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


            For Each iELE In IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("js-username-field email-input js-initial-focus")

                    If iELE.Value = "" Then
                            iELE.Value = xUser
                    End If
                Exit For
            Next
            For Each iELE In IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("js-password-field")

                    If iELE.Value = "" Then
                            iELE.Value = xPswd
                    End If
                Exit For
            Next
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
            For Each iELE In IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("submit EdgeButton EdgeButton--primary EdgeButtom--medium")

                    If iELE.Value = "" Then
                            iELE.Click
                    End If
                Exit For
            Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub Login(MyLogin, MyPass, strUrl)
    Dim IeApp As InternetExplorer
    Dim IeDoc As Object
    Dim ieTable As Object
    Set IeApp = New InternetExplorer
        IeApp.Visible = False
            IeApp.Navigate strUrl
            Do While IeApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
            Do Until IeApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
            Set IeDoc = IeApp.Document
                With IeDoc
                    .getElementsByClassName("js-username-field")(0).value = MyLogin
                    .getElementsByClassName("js-password-field")(0).value = MyPass
                End With
                IeDoc.getElementsByClassName("submit")(0).Click
                    Do While IeApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
                    Do Until IeApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

End Sub
```

https://www.pk-anexcelexpert.com/vba-web-browser-in-the-user-form/

Comment: My code already opens Internet Explorer and works correctly. I need to do the same procedure, but instead of opening Internet Explorer, I need to run in my userform webbrowser1

Comment: without opening or without using? without opening `IeApp.Visible = False` or you look for this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n49LRwy2EUA ?